# Single inheritance polymorphism

Tags: c++, beginner, polymorphism

I am learning about polymorphism in C++ and decided to implement an example. Is there anything I need to fix in my code? This compiles and runs.

```
#include <iostream>


using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;


class Employee
{
public:
    Employee():salary(1000){}
    virtual ~Employee(){}
    virtual void Talk() const {cout << "Employee says: ";}

protected:
    int salary;
};

class Programmer : public Employee
{
public:
    void Talk() const {cout << "I am a Programmer.\n";}
    void Compiling() const {cout << "My code is compiling...\n";}
};

class SalesPerson : public Employee
{
public:
    void Talk() const {cout << "I am a SalesRep.\n";}
    void Selling() const {};
};


int main()
{
    const int numEmployees = 3;
    Employee* Company[numEmployees];
    Employee* pEmployee;

    int choice,i;

    for(i=0; i<numEmployees; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "(1) Programmer (2) SalesRep: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 1)
            pEmployee = new Programmer;
        else
            pEmployee = new SalesPerson;

        Company[i] = pEmployee;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(i = 0; i<numEmployees;i++)
    {
        Company[i]->Talk();

        Programmer *pCoder = dynamic_cast<Programmer *> (Company[i]);

        if(pCoder)
            pCoder->Compiling();


        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `Selling()` supposed to be empty? What is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things I noticed at once:

There is something wrong in this `for`-loop:

```
for(i = 0; i<numEmployees;i++)
{
    Company[i]->Talk();

    Programmer *pCoder = dynamic_cast<Programmer *> (Company[i]);

    if(pCoder)
        pCoder->Compiling();


    cout << endl;
}
```

1. There is a memory leak. You need to add `delete Company[i]`
2. You aren't using the `Employee` object polymorphically.

Why are you doing this?

> ```
> Programmer *pCoder = dynamic_cast<Programmer *> (Company[i]);
> ```

You are trying to get at a method that doesn't seem appropriate for the base class. `Compiling()` is a method specific to the derived class `Programmer` What you are doing is a bit "hacky". It works because the base pointer is checked at runtime. You added an if-statement, so I assume you are at least aware.

In the future, do not access methods that are specific to derived classes through the base pointer.

You are `using std::cout`. I would keep it consistent and remove `std::` from
`std::cout << "(1) Programmer (2) SalesRep: ";`.

Comment: Adding `delete Company[i]` is a bad advice. `std::unique_ptr` would be much better.

Answer (score 6):

**Problems with your interface design**:

The `Employee` interface you've designed is clearly lacking
abstraction, since you have a `dynamic_cast` in the program to
test if an employee is of a specific type.

`Employee` should instead have a virtual method such as `DoWork()`
which in turn will call `Compiling()` for `Programmer`,
`Selling` for a `SalesPerson` and so forth:

```
class Employee 
{
public:
    ....

    // Virtual function with no default implementation (= 0)
    virtual void DoWork() const = 0;
};

class Programmer 
{
public:
    void DoWork() const { Compiling(); }
};

class SalesPerson
{
public:
    void DoWork() const { Selling(); }
};
```

The constructor of `Employee` sets `salary` to `1000` unconditionally.
Perhaps it would be better to take `salary` as a constructor parameter 
so you can easily specify different salaries:

```
Employee(double salary) : salary(salary) { }
```

BTW, `double` seems more appropriate for a monetary value, as it
is likely to include decimal places. `int` is for whole numbers only.

The destructor of `Employee` is empty, so it should be made a default:

```
virtual ~Employee() = default;
```

**Memory management tidbits**:

It is generally better to avoid manual memory management, as it is
error prone, not exception safe, and slipping a memory leak is very easy.
In fact, in your current example, the objects you've allocated
with `new` are not being destroyed. Remember that C++ is not garbage collected. You would have to `delete` them somewhere.

You should ideally be using an automatic pointer to manage
your dynamic instances. `main()` could be reworked in the following way:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Employee>, 3> company;

    int choice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < company.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "(1) Programmer (2) SalesRep: ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            company[i].reset( new Programmer );
        }
        else
        {
            company[i].reset( new SalesPerson );
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

You should note in the example above the use of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and
[`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). The `unique_ptr` is a managed pointer that will delete
the object automatically when you leave the function scope. This way
you don't have to worry about memory leaks. `std::array` is a fixed size
array which behaves just like a plain C array, but with some extra member
methods and debug bounds checking. It also knows its length, so we no longer
need to keep that `numEmployees` constant around.

Answer (score 2):

Adding what EngieOP suggested `Programmer *pCoder = dynamic_cast<Programmer *> (Company[i]);`
is not proper, instead use a common method to identify the class, e.g. have a method named `employee_identification` which just returns what type of employee he/she is.

For example:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee():salary(1000){}
    virtual ~Employee(){}
    virtual void Talk() const {cout << "Employee says: ";}
    virtual int employee_identification(){
            return 0; //ENUM can be used for better description.
        };

protected:
    int salary;
};

class Programmer : public Employee
{
public:
    void Talk() const {cout << "I am a Programmer.\n";}
    void Compiling() const {cout << "My code is compiling...\n";}
    int employee_identification(){
            return 1; // (1) Programmer.
        };
};

class SalesPerson : public Employee
{
public:
    void Talk() const {cout << "I am a SalesRep.\n";}
    void Selling() const {};
    int employee_identification(){
            return 2; // (2) SalesPerson.
        };
};
```

Now after you can change main as follows,

```
switch (pCoder->employee_identification())
{
     case 1:
        pCode->Compiling();
        break;
     case 2:
        pCode->Selling();
        break;
     default:
         cout<<"Wrong employee id\n"
}
```

Comment: Even better than the `switch`, the top level interface `Employee` should have a method `DoWork()` or similar that calls either `Compiling()`, `Selling()`, etc.

Comment: Yes that's also better idea.

Comment: The dynamic_cast is still a bit better than the employee_identification() "trick" (especially with an undocumented enum). At least it pollutes less classes, and can be searched for. But a real abstract method DoWork() like suggested is much better.

Comment: DoWork() better for sure, but if we use dynamic cast how do we know what type of object is present in  `company[i]` in second for loop?

Comment: Downcasting with dynamic_cast (on pointers) returns 0 on failure. The following "if" is how we know the type (or whether it is a Programmer at least).

Comment: Oh i didn't know that. Thank you for info. In that case, may be OP's solution is better than mine.

Comment: Accepting the problem of working with Employee's and then suddenly wondering whether they're actually Programmer's, dynamic_cast is the cleanest solution in my opinion. With some employee_identification(), this will fail with subclasses of Programmer, whereas they actually have a Compiling() method.

Comment: I don't have sufficient points to upvote your comments, upvoting it virtually :) thank your for explanation. In process of helping i learnt much more.